# Certificate problems when loading App on Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

A few days ago my certificates expired (not that i got a warning they were due to expire), and so i had to renew them.

previously i was able to load apps onto any device here easily, but now it doesnt.

i tried to renew or request new certificates on the provisioning portal (which seems to be way to over complicated!!) -  i followed the videos on there to help me, and managed to get it working on my iPhone. However when i try and install on my ipad i get:

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found
```

I googled this and found that i needed to remove the old certificates, so i deleted ALL of them and started fresh. went through the videos again and managed to get it working on on iPad, but now i get the above message when i try and install on iPhone.

I have checked the Devices list on the portal, and they are both listed on there.

can anyone help me with this? or give me clearer instructions on what i need to do to get things back to how they were before this happened.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the new provisioning profile includes both devices.  You can inspect the profile before downloading it from the portal.  Then delete old copies of the provision from the Xcode Organizer window and both your devices.  Download the new provision file to your Mac, and use the Xcode Organizer to put that profile on both devices.  Make sure to select that profile in the Debug Build settings before building and running your app.

Answer (score 0):

Your question duplicates the following link.

Check with the following url for your problem:

[A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found for debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Check the provisioning profile contains UDID of both the device (Iphone & Ipad). You check that from Organizer.