# Xcode keeps alternating two errors

Tags: xcode, rhomobile

When trying to run an app on a local iPhone, me and my coworker keep getting two errors that seem to be alternating every other build. The first is "a signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted", and the second is "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found". We've tried a lot of the common fixes, like deleting those weird db files from the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode folder. Any input at all would be very welcome, as we are both dumbfounded as to what could be going wrong.

Thank you in advance! If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with the Provisioning profile for ios device, its not related to the db files.

Your device is not recognized by the provisioning profile you are using for that application.

You can have a look at these posts, if they interest you,

[A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found for debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode)

[A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found... (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again)

Comment: I've already looked at both of those questions, and I realize what the problem is, I just don't know how to fix it... Thank you for trying though :)

Comment: Have you added the device's UUID to the Provisioning profile you are using? Also please check the identifier set for the provisioning profile matches with the identifier that your application is using.