# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found (Date / Time Settings)

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I simply want to debug on de iOS device.

I plug it in and I have the well known message "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found" issue.

I tried everything from posts such as [this post actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode)

I tried everything and still I keep having this message anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device "Date & Time" settings have "Set Automatically" activated.

If you are doing some specific tests on how your app behave with wrong Date & Time settings and really want to enter bad values ?

1. Set the date automatically to start your app the first time
2. Change the date as you wish
3. Then you will be able to start the app a certain number of times before it starts rejecting the certificate again.

Thanks,

Julien.