# ipa file does not contain a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa

I am facing an issue in Re signing of IPA file. My requirement is to rename the app and resign it with new provisioning profile and certificate. So i have changed the **"CFBundleIdentifier"** to the new app name. Then I followed the below steps to re sign the IPA file.

**extract the IPA file**:unzip Myapp.ipa

**remove existing code signature:**
rm -r "Payload/MyApp Mobile.app/_CodeSignature" "Payload/MyApp Mobile.app/CodeResources" 2> /dev/null | true

**replace the existing Provisioning Profile:**
cp "MyEnterprise.mobileprovision" "Payload/MyApp Mobile.app/embedded.mobileprovision"

**re-sign the executable:**
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Certificate Name" --resource-rules "Payload/MyApp Mobile.app/ResourceRules.plist" "Payload/MyApp Mobile.app"

**re-package the IPA file for distribution:**
zip -qr "MyApp.resigned.ipa" Payload

I am just re signing this IPA with the new Provisioning profile and the certificate which i have received from my vendor. I have followed the steps and resigned the app. While installing in Mobile Iron it is giving error as "ipa file does not contain provisioning profile". But i can see that my new provisioning profile is inside the IPA file.

Please anyone tell what could be the issue. I am new to this Apple app.

Comment: If you renamed your app then you have to create new provisioning profiles like its a new app. Make it clean please, do not change somethings but create news.

Comment: @yucelbayram My requirement is when the user download the app from the mobile iron it should be newMyApp earlier it was MyApp. So i have changed the "CFBundleIdentifier" to the new app name. Is this right way. If it is wrong then could you please suggest the solution and what are the information i would be required from my vendor.

Comment: As i understood someone changed your bundle name and you again changed it to earlier name but it doesn't work, is it true? You can change bundle name or product name as you want, only you have to create new profiles for this.  If you are sure you did everything right you just check your xcode's build settings>code signing.  For creating ipa these settings should be all ios distribution not ios development.

Comment: @yucelbayram App name is CFBundleDisplayName or CFBundleName. I already renamed CFBundleDisplayName and resigned using above steps. But the App is not getting installed in IPAD. And I am not aware of xcode. I am doing the change by using text editor and resigning by using terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your device UDID is not added in your provisioning profile.Most probably this error comes at this point.The following link can help you-

[A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found for debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode)

Comment: actually my requirement is to rename the app and resign it with new provisioning profile and certificate. So i have changed the "CFBundleIdentifier" to the new app name. Does this cause the issue?