# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found - OTA installation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, enterprise-distribution

I have a Enterprise distribution IOS app which can be installed via OTA url. But when i install that app using OTA url, installation will break showing the error message "**Unable to download  could not be install at this time**".

So I view the log of the iphone using device organizer in xcode and it shows this error regarding the installation: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found".

But that app can be installed to the same iphone using itunes and corresponding .ipa.

How this might be occur?

Comment: When you are creating ipa, check which provisioning profile is xcode using to create it. Sometimes Xcode mucks it up, it has happened to me as well. Make sure you have the proper profiles added and your bundle identifier corresponds to that profile correctly.

Comment: Refer this link,It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode

Comment: Are you sure the provisioning profile error is happening because of the OTA download.  Also, are you sure the manual install of the .ipa is the same one available on the site for OTA?  Finally, iOS does caching of server side downloads, so if the OTA site had an old version that had a bad profile, it may be cached on the device.  We always rename the file on the server for every new version we push to prevent cached versions from being picked up.  Also, make sure your OTA download site is using https.

Comment: Thanks @NSNoob it was issue with provisioning profile..

Comment: @HiChKu It is encouraged on SO to answer your own question and explain how you solved your problem.

Comment: Actually it is not a big deal.. i was careless to make the ios build with correct    provisioning profile or xcode mixed it up... Thanks every one for replies...

Comment: FYI.. IOS build which are build using wrong provisioning profile can some times can be installed in iphones which that app installed previously..