# react-native app fail to start after a few days

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I'm gonna try to explain the problem as clearly as possible, here are the steps:

- I compile the app on the device (width bundled file on disk - Options 2)
- The app starts, and work
- After a few days, when i click on the app's icon, it open the 'powered by react-native' screen, then it crash
- I had the same problem over multiple devices, and multiple times

I'm pretty sure it is not a JS error, since nothings change between the day it work, and the day it doesnt

here's the app logs on app start:

```
$ cat crachReport|grep MyApp

Aug 29 14:26:47 Abels-iPhone amfid[1524] <Notice>: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BDC567B0-B341-4B9A-8329-90B5CEC26440/MyApp.app/MyApp not valid: 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Aug 29 14:26:47 Abels-iPhone SpringBoard(BaseBoard)[1682] <Error>: Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp[0x9347]': No such process (err 3)
Aug 29 14:26:47 Abels-iPhone SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[1682] <Error>: Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1705f9500; org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp; pid: -1>
Aug 29 14:26:47 Abels-iPhone sharingd[62] <Notice>: SystemUI unknown identifier: 'org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp'
```

the `unfound provisionning profile` error does not appear on the logs when the app work, so i think it may come from here.

However i'm not sure since i'm new to ios developpement,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found for debug mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode)

Comment: @FuzzyTree Not the same, i can compile the app with the provisionning profile, it just seems to expire after a few days

Comment: I had the same issue, but just re-opening Xcode seemed to renew the provisioning profile for another 7 days and I didn't have to rebuild the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compilation with a valid provisionning profile, this problem does not appear.

The default provisionning profile was valid for 7 days, so the error was coming from there.