# iOS - Error - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using Xcode 9.1 and I have changed the developer account in Xcode. After making the change, I can build the project successfully but I cannot install it on the device. After building, Xcode says *A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.*

In my Info.plist I have an exception to the server in order to connect to it because it is not HTTPS

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
  <key>myUrl</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

In Targets->General I have automatically signing set.

In Targets->Build Settings->Code signing identity I have set iOS Developer on all fields

In Project->Build Settings->Code signing identity I have set iOS Developer on all fields

I have also deleted the previous version of the application from the iPhone.

Comment: Quit xcode and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found for debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode) - it has nothing to do with your `NSAppTransportSecurity` settings

Comment: @Sh_Khan I have tried that, is not working

Comment: @Flexicoder I saw that post but is very old and lots of answers as well. Xcode has been updated heaviley from than and lots of solutions people post there I cannot find in Xcode.

Comment: @P.Lorand you tried this answer from that question https://stackoverflow.com/a/42080321/285190 -

Comment: @Flexicoder Yes, Code signing style is set to Automatic.