# Xcode fails to run on device after cancelling Keychain access popup

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project which I built, deployed and released successfully for more than a year. Today, while working on it, Xcode popped up a permission dialog for accessing a keychain item. Stupid me hit the escape key. Starting from this time, all attmepts to run the project on a device failed with the error `A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found`.

So somehow I seem to have locked Xcode from accessing the provisioning profile data in the keychain. Is there a way to let Xcode re-ask me for access permission?

The project is configured to "automatically manage signing"; I have selected the correct team, and the provisioning profile info in the project settings shows all checkmarks, no issues.

So far I tried:

- unpair the device
- restart Xcode
- restart computer
- remove and re-add dev account (as suggested in the comments, thx @Paulw11)
- change the bundle id (as suggested in the comments, thx @matt)
- lock/unlock keychain (as suggested in the answer linked by @matt, thx again)

Please not, this question is *not* a duplicate of the many questions about how to run an app which contain the same error message (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode)).
My project setup is sound and used to work for months, and the current state of the codebase was runnable on a device 15 minutes ago, before the damn keychain popup incident.

Oh, and P.S.: I hate Xcode. Feel free to downvote me for this outburst of emotion, but it's a fact.

Comment: Try removing and reading your developer account in Xcode settings

Comment: Try changing your bundle id.

Comment: @Paulw11tried it, had no effect

Comment: @matt tried your solution too, had no effect either. I also tired the "duplicate" answer you linked to, no success as well. So please unmark the duplication so others can have a look at my question...

Comment: What about reverting to the Legacy Build System?

Comment: @matt thanks for the tip... any hint on how to do so? :) I did a quick research but only found some outdated 3rd party tools for deploying an .ipa to a device.

Comment: @matt got it, I had missed the 2nd "duplicate" link (which actually describes the very same issue I'm facing) where this is explained. I tried to change the build system in the workspace settings, interestingly I was already using the "legacy" mode; tried to switch to "new" build system. During the build Xcode actually asked me again for keychain access permissions; but, once the build succeeded, it failed again when trying to deploy to the device.

Comment: @matt update: finally got it working thanks to your hint about the build system settings, combined with a Clean and manually deleting derived data. Thanks a lot!